# How to handle load more button for IMDB using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, dataset, web-crawler

I want to scrape imdb movies data. I am using scrapy and I am able to extract all the movies title and other related information but I am having issue while trying to scrape movies review with load more button. My start_url is: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&primary_language=hi&sort=num_votes,desc

```
def parse(self, response):

    for result in response.css('.mode-advanced'):

        primaryTitle = result.css('div.lister-item-content h3.lister-item-header a::text').extract_first()          
        link = result.css('div.lister-item-content h3.lister-item-header a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        duration = result.css('div.lister-item-content p:nth-child(2) span.runtime::text').extract_first()
        genre = result.css('div.lister-item-content p:nth-child(2) span.genre::text').extract_first()

        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.imdb.com'+link,
                                callback=self.parse_listing,
                                meta={'primaryTitle':primaryTitle,
                                    'duration':duration,
                                    'genre':genre})
        

    next_page = response.css('.lister-page-next::attr(href)').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.imdb.com'+next_page, callback=self.parse)


def parse_listing(self, response):
    primaryTitle = response.meta['primaryTitle']
    duration = response.meta['duration']
    genre = response.meta['genre']

    fullTitle = response.css('.fbQftq h1.eKrKux::text').extract_first()
    description = response.css('div.hrgVKw span::text').extract()
    year = response.css('.fbQftq div.iJtmbR ul.baseAlt li:nth-child(1) a.WIUyh::text').extract_first()
    rating = response.css('.fAePGh div.kYEdvH span.jGRxWM::text').extract_first()
    director = response.css('div.fjLeDR ul.ipc-metadata-list--baseAlt li:nth-child(1) div ul.baseAlt li a::text').extract()
    writer = response.css('div.fjLeDR ul.ipc-metadata-list--baseAlt li:nth-child(2) div ul.baseAlt li a::text').extract()
    stars = response.css('div.fjLeDR ul.ipc-metadata-list--baseAlt li:nth-child(3) div ul.baseAlt li a::text').extract()
    votes = response.css('div.bZeUlh div.gopMqI::text').extract_first()

    review_link = response.css('div.gcCaSg ul.baseAlt li.ghlYSH a.isReview::attr(href)').extract_first()

    yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.imdb.com'+review_link,
                        callback=self.parse_review,
                        meta={'primaryTitle':primaryTitle,
                                'duration':duration,
                                'genre':genre,
                                'fullTitle':fullTitle,
                                'description':description,
                                'year':year,
                                'rating':rating,
                                'director':director,
                                'writer': writer,
                                'stars':stars,
                                'votes':votes})

def parse_review(self, response):
    primaryTitle = response.meta['primaryTitle']
    duration = response.meta['duration']
    genre = response.meta['genre']
    fullTitle = response.meta['fullTitle']
    description = response.meta['description']
    year = response.meta['year']
    rating = response.meta['rating']
    director = response.meta['director']
    writer = response.meta['writer']
    stars = response.meta['stars']
    votes = response.meta['votes']

    for review_details in response.css('div.lister-item-content'):

        review_rating = review_details.css('div.ipl-ratings-bar span.rating-other-user-rating span::text').extract_first()
        review_title = review_details.css('a.title::text').extract_first()
        username = review_details.css('div.display-name-date span.display-name-link a::text').extract_first()
        review_date = review_details.css('div.display-name-date span.review-date::text').extract_first()
        review_description = review_details.css('div.content div.show-more__control::text').extract_first()

        yield{'url': response.url,
            'primaryTitle': primaryTitle,
            'duration': duration,
            'genre': genre,
            'fullTitle': fullTitle,
            'description': description,
            'year': year,
            'duration':duration,
            'rating':rating,
            'director':director,
            'rating':rating,
            'director':director,
            'writer':writer,
            'stars':stars,
            'votes':votes,
            'review_rating':review_rating,
            'review_title':review_title,
            'username':username,
            'review_date':review_date,
            'description':description}

    
    base_url = 'https://www.imdb.com'
    review_ajaxurl = '/title/tt10811166/reviews/_ajax'
    paginationKey = 'g4wp7bjfqy2tg3yl7swh7nzqrht4uabhzfmxvlnomwklyczuf43o6ss4pe2vlmjncr4k4wendyfpwpblleaqtzauqo4rtea'


    load_more_url = base_url+review_ajaxurl+'?ref_=undefined&paginationKey='+paginationKey
    if load_more_url is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(url = load_more_url, callback=self.parse_review)
```

The problem is how can I crawl all the reviews for movies using scrapy from load more button (IMDB).

Comment: your start url is not working

Comment: it may need to use scrapy with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  (module `scrapy_selenium`)  to click button on page. And if you get directly from ajax then you may get it as JSON data and you may need to create new function to parse it.

Comment: it has page https://developer.imdb.com/ with information about API. Maybe it will be simpler method - if only it gives all needed data.